# How to decide whether logic goes in on client side vs server side in react redux express app

Tags: express, reactjs, server, client, redux

Newbie here, trying to get a better understanding of react, redux, and express. I've seen so many examples that have redux on both the client and the server side, with varying ways of passing info back and forth (sockets, etc..?). It's pretty confusing for a beginner.

Say I had an app that:

- Connected to an external api to search for a restaurant, or get a list of restaurants near a location (like a yelp api or something)
- User could search for a specific restaurant or look through the location results, to add a place to their own favorites list

I assume the communication to the external api is on the server side but past that I'm unsure which logic belongs where, whether I'll need redux on the client and/or server side, and what the best practice for passing that api info to the client in a react/redux app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server-side rendering with redux is just an *optimization* under certain circumstances.

- If you have lots of server&money and want to optimize for speed => render server-side. This is what many companies do which results in all the tutorials/examples of server-side rendering.
- If you want to optimize for code simplicity => render client-side
- If you want to optimize for minimal server load => render client-side

If you are just staring out using react/redux => go for client-side rendering.

> what the best practice for passing that api info to the client in a react/redux app.

Go for simplicity, especially when starting out.
You can use a simple XHR library like `superagent` to communicate between the client (react/redux) and the server (node server with express?)